# Finding the equivalence class of an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

[image]

I am not quite sure what this question means.

Are these equivalence classes valid as each element within a set can be rounded up to become the same integer?

{0.5,0.51}, {1.5, 1.51}, {2.5,2.51}, {3.5,3.51}, {4.5,4.51}

Comment: Although $0.5$ and $0.51$ belong to the same equivalence class, there are infinitely many other elements also in the same equivalence class.  The equivalence class containing $0.5$ will be the set *of all* numbers from the domain which are related to $0.5$.  Worded another way, the equivalence class containing $0.5$ will be the set of all real numbers which round up to the same number as $0.5$ rounds up to.  How else can we describe this set? There will be other different equivalence classes for this equivalence relation as well which $0.5$ is not a part of. What are those and how to describe?

Comment: are the other classes integers? I am not too sure how to describe.

Comment: No...  I'll try to explain again.  Notice that all of the following numbers round up to $2$:   $1.1,1.11,1.2,1.21,\sqrt{2},\frac{\pi}{3},1.5,1.51,1.501,1.9999\dots,2$.  Notice also that this is necessarily an incomplete list.  Since they all round up to $2$, the are all "related" according to this equivalence relation and as such will all belong to the same equivalence class.  Note further that $1.5$ rounds up to a different number than $0.5$ and these both round up to a different number than $2.5, 3.5, 4.5,$ and even $0$.

Comment: So... you have the following equivalence classes:  The set of all real numbers who round up to $5$, the set of all real numbers who round up to $4$, the set of all real numbers who round up to $3$,..., the set of all real numbers (*from our domain!*) who round up to $0$.  Each of these can be written more concisely using more common mathematical terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

Given an equivalence relation it **partitions** the given ground set $X$ (the interval $[0,5]$ in the present example) into **disjoint subsets**. These subsets are called **equivalence classes**. Two elements $x$, $y\in X$ belong to the same class iff they are equivalent. In the given example the numbers $\pi$ and ${1\over\pi}$ are not equivalent (check this!), hence they belong to different equivalence classes. The equivalence class containing the number $4$ contains all real numbers $x$ satisfying $3<x\leq4$.

Comment: is the one 'special' class the integer 4 in your particular example?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $R$ is a relation on some set $X$ and is prescribed by:$$xRy\iff f(x)=f(y)$$where $f$ denotes some function that has $X$ as codomain then $R$ is an equivalence relation and the equivalence class represented by $x$ is the set: $$f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})=\{y\in X\mid f(y)=f(x)\}$$